# getProperty() is undefined for the type AudioManager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-audiomanager

I have a problem with API 17 AudioManager's method `getProperty`

Eclipse can't recognize this method and displays:

`The method getProperty() is undefined for the type AudioManager`

I have updated Eclipse and packages in Android SDK Manager. API 17 is installed and up to date.

> Eclipse Version: 4.2.2
>
> Build id: M20130204-1200

sample code:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
```

Comment: plz show your code how you are trying to access setProperty() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me if I set the Android version for my project to 4.2.2.

```
String s = am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
```

Right-click your project in the package explorer, click `Properties`, `Android`, set `Project Build Target` to `Android 4.2.2` and click `Apply`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the sdk level set in your projects AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and just to be safe, in project.properties:

```
# Project target.
target=android-17
```